# How to prevent employees to work from home on the company's django application

Tags: django, web-applications

I built an ERP for a small company using **Django 1.11**. They are expanding now and have other companies joining them and now also use the system I built.

The problem now is that some of the companies do not want their employees to be able to work from outside of the company's premises; remotely. Is there a way to achieve this on the Django application? Is there a way to tweak the Django's **allowed_host** setting for this purpose? Should I be checking for the location of the user connecting to the app? If so, how do I prevent the app from being fooled by those using a VPN service?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS` denotes the allowed hostnames for the *server* (e.g. www.example.com), not the clients. You should use a firewall to selectively block IP addresses and allow only LAN IPs. If the users can VPN into the company network, there is nothing you can do as technically they are _inside_ the company. If you mean using an anonymizing VPN, it is irrelevant as they will be blocked too.

Comment: Is **use a firewall to selectively block IP addresses and allow only LAN IPs** a global solution? If it is; it is going to hurt the other companies that might favor the ability to work remotely

Comment: I see, so you want _some users_ to be able to work remotely. I guess you should then use the authentication system to differentiate users. Write a middleware that checks the HTTP_REFERER header to get the IP address, then match this with the logged in user.

Comment: Delegate this task to your Network/Security Team. I think investing efforts at Django Level (app level) is not worth. 
Yup - Anyone coming into network via VPN will off course have IP addresses dedicated for VPN users. So network/security team will know how to block those IP's/Blocks of IP addresses.